# handlebars:compile - Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined use

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I've been searching around but there seemed to be no situation similar to mine so thought I'd post to ask. I want to run the handlebars task in Gruntfile.js with *grunt handlebars* to compile a templates.js in my source folder (www) but it doesn't fire up with this error shown:

> Warning: Cannot read property '**filter**' of undefined Use

Here's my script for the handlebars task in grunt file:

```
// Create the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

  config: config,

  handlebars: {
    // Compiles the handlebar templates into templates.js
    compile: {
      options: {
        amd: true,
        processName: function (filepath) {
          var pieces = filepath.split('/');
          return pieces[pieces.length - 1].split('.')[0];
        }
      },
      // Specify location of handlebar templates
      www: ['<%= config.www %>/html/{,*/}*.handlebars'],
      dest: '<%= config.www %>/js/templates.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Here's opening script of grunt file and the config object, before grunt.initConfig :

```
module.exports = (function () {

    'use strict';

    return function (grunt) {

      require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // Several tasks to run using grunt-contrib-xx plugins

      // Config object
      var config = {
        www: 'www',                // all source files in one directory
      };
        ..                        // grunt.initConfig
    };
});
```

Couldn't figure out what goes wrong here since I don't even define a property/term filter and that's the only error received. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It's likely a typo. `www: ['<%= ...` should probably be `src: ['<%= ...`.

Comment: I changed it to 'src' as the specified source and now it works brilliantly. It's all casual mistake with the source folder name and the property itself. Thank you @cartant!

Comment: @G.Jones write it as an answer to your own question and accept it. that would help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will write what I did to resolve this which might be of use to you.

I simply changed the *www* property specifically to *src*, as referred to in the first code block, for the handlebars task in grunt file to fire up. Existing handlebars which are markups are **sourced** a.k.a. src and to compile the templates.js in your specified destination.

Note: handlebars file itself should end with unspecified file type (.handlebars). Depending on your own set up, noting this will save you lots of time afterwards.

Now run below and you shall see the templates.js found in the *dest* folder.

> grunt handlebars